# How and why does this SIMPLE For loop using range work for printing a simple 3D array in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array

I tried to use the range function this way to print a board and it just worked, but I can't resolve why ? How is the row, column count interrated over?

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var board [2][2][2]string

    for row := range board {
        for column := range board {
            for third := range board {
                fmt.Print(row, column, third)
                fmt.Println()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. You're iterating over the top-level array in each loop. The fact that every array has exactly 2 elements gives you the illusion of success. The failure is more obvious if you print out the values, rather than the indexes ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ioETiagLh8D)):

```
var board = [2][2][2]string{
    {
        {"a", "b"},
        {"c", "d"},
    },
    {
        {"e", "f"},
        {"g", "h"},
    },
}

for _, rowValue := range board {
    for _, columnValue := range board {
        for _, thirdValue := range board {
            fmt.Println(rowValue, columnValue, thirdValue)
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }
}
```

What you want is for each inner loop to iterate over the inner array ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/ruwGDQKdYdx)):

```
for _, rowValue := range board {
    for _, columnValue := range rowValue {
        for _, thirdValue := range columnValue {
            fmt.Printf("\t%s", thirdValue)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n\n")
}
```

which gives this output:

```
a   b
c   d


e   f
g   h
```